# can a football receiver tip the ball to another receiver?

Tags: rules, american-football, collegiate

In NCAA football, can a receiver tap the ball to another receiver, similar to a volleyball pass. I thought once an offensive receiver touched the ball it was an incomplete pass if a defensive player didn't touch the ball in between.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an eligible receiver may tap or bat the ball.  Here is a relevant interpretation from the [NCAA Rulebook](https://www.ncaapublications.com/p-4387-2015-ncaa-football-rules-and-interpretations.aspx).

Approved ruling 7-3-6 VIII (Page FI-41)

> While airborne and in bounds, eligible receiver A89 touches a forward
>   pass when he propels it toward: (a) eligible receiver A80, who catches
>   the pass; or (b) B27, who intercepts the pass. RULING: Legal play, and
>   the ball remains live in both (a) and (b). A89 has batted a forward
>   pass (Rules 2-4-3, 2-11-3 and 9-4-1-a).

The mentioned 9-4-1-a rule seems especially relevant:

> While a pass is in flight, only a player who is eligible to touch the
>   ball may bat it in any direction (Exception: Rule 9-4-2).